# Pyjoystick inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, sdl, joystick

I am trying to to handle commands from my xbox one controller inside a docker container.

I am running the container in privileged mode and using xow as driver. It detects the controller and pairs inside my container:

```
root@5e6c8573010e:/app# ./xow
2022-08-25 08:56:01 INFO  - xow v0.5-36-gd335d60 ©Severin v. W.
2022-08-25 08:56:01 INFO  - Waiting for device...
2022-08-25 08:56:01 INFO  - Wireless address: 62:45:b4:e7:6d:70
2022-08-25 08:56:01 INFO  - Dongle initialized
2022-08-25 08:56:05 INFO  - Controller '1' connected
2022-08-25 08:56:05 INFO  - Device announced, product id: 02dd
2022-08-25 08:56:05 INFO  - Serial number: 02980116127538
```

However, when I run my python script to access the commands

```
from pyjoystick.sdl2 import Key, Joystick, run_event_loop

def print_add(joy):
    print('Added', joy)

run_event_loop(print_add, print_remove, key_received)
```

it does not detect the controller. The script runs without errors but is just not saying "Added". My host system says "Added" if I run the script there, though.

How can this be? Some missing dependencies in the SDL lib?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue by observing my device folder after starting the driver.
In my host system, the devices

```
/dev/input/event0
/dev/input/js0
```

were created but not shown in the docker container.

I solved this by adding this option

```
-v /dev/input:/dev/input
```

to my run script.

The driver itself needs

```
-v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb
```

to access the dongle for remote connection which is plugged into one of my raspberry pis usb ports.

Now I can cloud deploy some remote container which gives my remote target access to xbox one controllers.